# Copy and delete a directory with WordPress functions

Tags: functions, directory, wp-filesystem

I have successfully used `copy_dir()` to copy a directory to a new location. How can I delete a directory using WordPress functions?

Comment: WP_Filesystem();
copy_dir(source,des); worked! , how to delete?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method [`rmdir()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_filesystem_base/rmdir/) - [source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-base.php#L782) - :

```
/**
 * Delete a directory.
 *
 * @since 2.5.0
 *
 * @param string $path Path to directory.
 * @param bool $recursive Optional. Whether to recursively remove files/directories.
 * Default false.
 * @return bool Whether directory is deleted successfully or not.
 */
public function rmdir( $path, $recursive = false ) {
    return false;
}
```

from the [`WP_Filesystem_Base`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-base.php#L14) class should work for that purpose.

The method `rmdir()` is part of the classes that extend `WP_Filesystem_Base`, like [`WP_Filesystem_Direct`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-direct.php#L17) and accordingly there is the [`rmdir()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-direct.php#L326) method in that class. Take a look at the the [`wp-admin/includes`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/tree/master/wp-admin/includes) directory to inspect the other classes yourself.

So just copy the directory with [`copy_dir()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/copy_dir/) - [source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/file.php#L768) - and then remove it with above method.

A bit more general information about the [Filesystem API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Filesystem_API) can be found at the codex page.