# How to copy one folder to another folder recursively

Tags: directory

I want copy all the files of a folder to another folder. So how to copy recursively in wordpress.

Comment: What files? From where to where?

Comment: I want to copy all the files from one of my plugin  inside plugins directory to the active theme directory.

Comment: Please: As (usual as) [edit]. Also, please read [ask].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make use of the [`Filesystem API`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Filesystem_API), especially the [`copy_dir()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/copy_dir/) function - [source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/985bed281cafa059ecad01bfe89277ea41ef4bd2/wp-admin/includes/file.php#L1398) - does seem to be what you are looking for. Take a look at the docblock from the above source link for a little bit more information:

```
/**
* Copies a directory from one location to another via the WordPress Filesystem Abstraction.
* Assumes that WP_Filesystem() has already been called and setup.
*
* @since 2.5.0
*
* @param string $from source directory
* @param string $to destination directory
* @param array $skip_list a list of files/folders to skip copying
* @return mixed WP_Error on failure, True on success.
*/
```

The (very) basic usage scenario would look like this:

```
global $wp_filesystem;
copy_dir( 
    '/path/you/are/copying/from/', 
    '/path/you/are/copying/to/'
);
```

Unfortunately the `Filesystem API` isn't exactly well documented. You definitely should take a look at the linked codex article. One additional (almost always) linked source of information would be the article by @Otto:

- [Tutorial: Using the WP_Filesystem](http://ottopress.com/2011/tutorial-using-the-wp_filesystem/)

Besides that there are some Q&A's on here which might be helpful:

- [Using wp_filesystem in Plugins](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/124900/22534)
- [Use WP_Filesystem to list files in directory](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/160823/22534)
- [Copy and delete a directory with WordPress functions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/159619/22534)

Note, the above are just a small sample, use the [search](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=wp_filesystem) to find more. Last but not least, to take a closer look at the source to learn and know more about it should definitely be on your agenda.